# Programmatically Obtain Port #s from my NIC using C++

Tags: c++, networking

I was curious what options there may be to obtain the physical port information from a NIC that I can then use as a failover should connectivity be lost.  I.E.  the wire on port0 is pulled, my program recognizes this and fails over to port1 to maintain the connection.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing multiple concepts here:

- First of all, it really depends on how networking on your machine is set. Do you have multiple NICs connected to the same network(s)? Are they treated as single logical adapter?
- Secondly, assuming your OS level networking just uses each NIC for a separate route entry, if the cable is pulled, your program will see an EOF on the next `read()` (or a signal on the next `write()`). In which case, you could re-establish your connection (without concerning which NIC is actually being used).
- In general, you cannot pretend the connection has not been terminated at the library level. OS might provide some low-level magic to do something like this but at the sockets level you will have to re-establish connection (i.e. both endpoints will sense the connection termination).

Comment: Will see EOF. Basically what he wants to achieve should be partially achieved at the lower level of the protocol stack than where he wants to solve it. If the NIC's are pointing to different routes, the router protocols should handle the failover (given that the target is reachable from both NICs), however this won't be transparent, needs connection re-establishment on the app level. If the NICs are connected to the same network, then we are talking about trunking, which is a special thing, needs driver and OS co-operation too. This may not provide auto failover either.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Alexander.

However, if you are running a version of linux, and still want to to know about all things network related, take a look in `/proc/net`, in particular the `dev` and `tcp` files.

Here's a good starting point: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can as others stated.

If you want to do circuit (not just connection) failover, I think you have to do it in a switch (hardware).